# Right cosets $\Gamma_1(N) \cap\alpha^{-1} \Gamma_1(N)\alpha$ in $\Gamma_1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-forms

In the book *Introduction to Elliptic Curves and Modular Form*s from *Neal Koblitz* there is a certain step in the solution of an exercise that is left to the reader (IV.3, Problem 5 and solution). Since I failed to show this step I hope that someone here could help me.

First we define

$\Gamma_0(N) := \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) : c \equiv 0\mod N \right\}$

$\Gamma_1(N) := \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma_0(N) : a \equiv d \equiv 1\mod N \right\}$.

Let $\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma_0(N)$ be such that $p^2 \mid b$. 
Let $\gamma_j \in \Gamma_1(N)$ and $\tau_j = \gamma^{-1}\gamma_j \gamma \in \Gamma_1(N)$.

Now comes the mentioned step:
Verify that if $\tau_{j}$ and $\tau_{j'}$ are in the same right coset of $\Gamma_1(N) \cap\alpha^{-1} \Gamma_1(N)\alpha$ in $\Gamma_1$ where $\alpha = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & p \end{pmatrix}$ and $p>2$ prime then so are $\gamma_j=\gamma \tau_j\gamma^{-1}$ and $\gamma_{j'}=\gamma \tau_{j'}\gamma^{-1}$.

If I'm not mistaken, then I have to show:
Suppose $\tau_j = \beta \tau_{j'}$ for a $\beta \in \Gamma_1(N)$ then there exists $\tilde{\beta} \in \Gamma_1(N)$ such that $\gamma_j = \tilde{\beta}\gamma_{j'}$.

This seems like an easy problem in an algebra class, but I was not able to do prove that...

I'm only interested in the case $p|N$, if it helps you.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: @user1952009: It denotes the set of right cosets $\{ \Gamma_1(N)a: a \in \Gamma_1(N)\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & p \end{pmatrix} \Gamma_1(N) \}$ of $\Gamma_1(N)$ in $\Gamma_1(N)\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & p \end{pmatrix} \Gamma_1(N) $. Is this an unusual notation? If yes, then I will edit the post to clarify.

Comment: I think it meant $p \equiv 1 \bmod N$, and $F  = \Gamma_1(N) \setminus E$ where $E = \{ u \ \mid  \ \ u = v \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & p \end{pmatrix} v  , \ \ v \in \Gamma_1(N) \ \}$

Comment: @user1952009: I edited the post. Does it make more sense now? (Thanks for reading/helping)

Comment: told you, I don't get how it works if $p \not\equiv 1 \bmod N$

Comment: @user1952009: Why do we require $ p \equiv 1 \mod N$?